# F# Interactive with nuget reference: namespace not defined

Tags: f#, reference, fsi

I am trying to use the Select.HtmlToPdf library https://www.nuget.org/packages/Select.HtmlToPdf/20.2.0

```
#r "nuget: Select.HtmlToPdf, 20.2.0"

open Select.HtmlToPdf
```

After sending the reference to the FSI, it returns a path to ...\Project.fsproj.fsx and `namespace FSI_0004.Project`

After sending the open statement to FSI, I get

> The namespace or module "Select" is not defined.

I am pretty new to F#, hope somebody can explain how I have to do this.

Thanks

EDIT: I use Visual Studio Code and/or Jupyter lab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library is called `Select.HtmlToPdf`, but the namespace it uses is `SelectPdf`, so this should work:

```
#r "nuget: Select.HtmlToPdf, 20.2.0"

open SelectPdf
```

Comment: Thanks, Since this was not working right away, I referenced the ` #r "nuget: Select.HtmlToPdf.NetCore, 20.2.0" `first. That together with your explanation, solved the problem.